Why are child components remounting upon parent state change when using MUI Paper/Styled?
When a child component is wrapped in an MUI-styled Paper component, it remounts each time there is a change in the parent state being passed as a prop.
I've created a minimum working example of this unintended behavior below. If you simply remove the <Item> from the parent component, the child will render instead of re-mounting. I'm hoping someone can explain why this behavior is occurring.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const ChildComponent = ({ testValue }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("I've been mounted");
      }, []); 

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Test Value: {testValue}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [testValue, setTestValue] = useState("Initial Value");

    const Item = styled(Paper)({
      textAlign: 'center',
    }); 

    const handleChangeValue = () => {
        setTestValue("Updated Value");
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleChangeValue}>Change Test Value</button>
            <Item>
            <ChildComponent testValue={testValue} />
            </Item>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ParentComponent;


Don't create component inside another component. Move Item outside of ParentComponent. You are recreating it on each render. The diffing algorithm can't compare that

Try moving your Item definition outside of the ParentComponent definition:
const Item = styled(Paper)({
  textAlign: 'center',
}); 

const ParentComponent = () => { ... }

When you change state inside ParentComponent, it re-runs all the code inside that component. So your "Item" component is getting reinitialized with each state change, forcing its children to re-mount, since it's treated like a whole new component.
